# How do I access git code locally in a branch?

Tags: github, checkout

I like to edit git code that resides in branches. Every time I git checkout into the master, the windows system hides the branch code. So the only way to access that branch code is to git checkout back into it. Is there a way to direct a local editor to open code that's in a hidden branch w/o checkout?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to open some branch code in an editor to refer back to an example there, without having to checkout constantly, back and forth.

Answer (score 2):

To create a branch in git, open your command line terminal, and type:

```
git branch
```

This will show you all of your current branches. Then, to create a new branch, enter

```
git checkout -b <branch-name>
```